# Mathematica - restricting x interval in loop

Tags: loops, wolfram-mathematica, intervals

I'm trying to perform a Do loop like this in Mathematica, where at each step both g and f are recalculated using the previous value of f:

```
nend=1000;
f[x_] = Tanh[x];
Do[
   g[x_] = f[x]^3 + f[x] + Laplacian[f[x], {x}];
   f[x_] = f[x] + 0.01 g[x],                     
   {i, 0, nend}
]
```

It appears to work for very small values of nend (up to nend=3!), but the kernel stops and quits when I try to use greater values. I'm guessing it has to do with the loop being computed for all x from -Inf to Inf. Since I'm only interested in the interval [-10,10], is there a way to restrict the loop to those values of x?

I'm also interested in any other suggestions on how to do the same thing in a more efficient way.

I'm working with Mathematica 11.0 in Debian 9.

Thanks!

Comment: This is slightly simpler `nend = 4; f[x_]=Tanh[x]; Do[g[x_] = Simplify[f[x]^3+f[x]+ Laplacian[f[x], {x}]]; f[x_] = Simplify[f[x]+0.01 g[x]], {i,0,nend}]; f[x]` and shows you how the size of your expression grows as nend grows.

Comment: Hi, @Bill. Maybe I didn't make myself clear. What you are suggesting is the same I already have, except for the use of Simplify. It has the same problem I presented in my original post: both my example and yours work for very small values of nend (up to 3), and I want to be able to use nend=1000 or bigger. Do you have any suggestions on restricting the x range in the do loop? Thanks for your answer, anyway!

Comment: Without my "just using Simplify" the number of symbols needed for Mathematica to find your result for nend=1,2,3,4,5,6 is 181, 1028, 6290, 40665, 273576, 1895961 and for nend=1000 that would need more than 10^779 symbols. With my "just using Simplify" the numbers are 127, 300, 840, 3233... which will take longer but use far less memory. Neither of those are going to get to nend=1000. There is no "being computed for all x from -Inf to Inf" in your code. The only thing being done is exactly calculating derivatives on your growing tower of functions f and g. Can you simply explain what you want?

Comment: I'm sorry if I came across rude. I am aware of what Simplify does, and I agree that my code is much better with it. What I want, in simple words, is to be able to compute that sum up to big values of nend, at least for x in [-10,10].

Answer (score 1):

MMA computes most things exactly or almost exactly. It is exactly computing the 181 symbols needed for {f[x],g[x]} when nend==1 or the 97131923 symbols needed when nend==8, as long as you aren't using Simplify. It isn't going to throw away millions of those terms whether x==1 or x==10^999, unless you find some much simpler way to tell it to approximate your problem. So the number of terms you are generating and the size of the resulting calculation does not depend on the range of x.

Perhaps you can look at the result, decide if you really need nend==1000 and try to decide how to get there while describing your problem to MMA in a way that it can do this on the computer and the memory that you have available.

```
a[x_] = Tanh[x];
Do[b[x_] = a[x]^3 + a[x] + Laplacian[a[x], {x}];
  a[x_] = a[x] + 0.01 b[x], {i, 0, 1}];
a1[x_] = a[x]; b1[x_] = b[x];
Do[b[x_] = a[x]^3 + a[x] + Laplacian[a[x], {x}];
  a[x_] = a[x] + 0.01 b[x], {i, 2, 2}];
a2[x_] = a[x]; b2[x_] = b[x];
Do[b[x_] = a[x]^3 + a[x] + Laplacian[a[x], {x}];
  a[x_] = a[x] + 0.01 b[x], {i, 3, 3}];
a3[x_] = a[x]; b3[x_] = b[x];
Do[b[x_] = a[x]^3 + a[x] + Laplacian[a[x], {x}];
  a[x_] = a[x] + 0.01 b[x], {i, 4, 4}];
a4[x_] = a[x]; b4[x_] = b[x];
Do[b[x_] = a[x]^3 + a[x] + Laplacian[a[x], {x}];
  a[x_] = a[x] + 0.01 b[x], {i, 5, 5}];
a5[x_] = a[x]; b5[x_] = b[x];
Do[b[x_] = a[x]^3 + a[x] + Laplacian[a[x], {x}];
  a[x_] = a[x] + 0.01 b[x], {i, 6, 6}];
a6[x_] = a[x]; b6[x_] = b[x];
Do[b[x_] = a[x]^3 + a[x] + Laplacian[a[x], {x}];
  a[x_] = a[x] + 0.01 b[x], {i, 7, 7}];
a7[x_] = a[x]; b7[x_] = b[x];
Do[b[x_] = a[x]^3 + a[x] + Laplacian[a[x], {x}];
  a[x_] = a[x] + 0.01 b[x], {i, 8, 8}];
a8[x_] = a[x]; b8[x_] = b[x];
Print[{LeafCount[{a1[x], b1[x]}], LeafCount[{a2[x], b2[x]}], 
       LeafCount[{a3[x], b3[x]}], LeafCount[{a4[x], b4[x]}], 
       LeafCount[{a5[x], b5[x]}], LeafCount[{a6[x], b6[x]}], 
       LeafCount[{a7[x], b7[x]}], LeafCount[{a8[x], b8[x]}]}];
Plot[{a1[x], b1[x], a2[x], b2[x], a3[x], b3[x], a4[x], b4[x], 
      a5[x], b5[x], a6[x], b6[x], a7[x], b7[x], a8[x], b8[x]}, {x, -3, 3}]
```

which displays

```
{181,1028,6290,40665,273576,1895961,13445784,97131923}
```

and then the plots of your pairs of curves for each value of nend.

[image]

I did each of your iterations of your Do loop separately so that I could save a copies of the curves to plot for each value of nend.

The modest difference between the bottom b1[x] orange curve and the top b4[x] orange curve are the difference between 79 terms and 18614 terms in your calculation when nend==1 versus nend==4.

Your plot for `a` changes slightly depending on the value of nend, in spite of a1[x] having 101 terms and a4[x] having 22047 terms. Here is a the plot of `a1` with `Tanh[x]` superimposed and there isn't a great deal of difference.

[image]

Your plots of `b` change a little more depending on the value of nend and it isn't so obvious what function those might be approaching. I tried subtracting a from b, thinking that might show me something, but that didn't help.

The number of terms you are generating as you iterate over and over is going to grow to be beyond what any computer will ever be able to deal with.

If you want to calculate up to nend==1000 then I think you need to find some way to approximate the calculation at each step so that you do not lose essential information, but that you do not increase the number of terms by 4x or 8x with each iteration.

Perhaps at the end of each iteration and after you use Simplify you could then calculate the value of each term at x==10 and if the result was perhaps less than 10^-6 you could then replace that term with zero. That might help you combat the exponential explosion in the number of terms that you generate with each iteration while still preserving the behavior of your calculation.

If there is any way you can do it, throwing LOTS of memory at MMA is almost always a good idea. 16GB or 32GB or even 64GB if there is any way you can get that will often help. Memory isn't as cheap as it was a few years ago, but if you can afford it and your machine can use it then getting all the memory you can would be a good step, particularly if you don't want to spend lots of time trying to find a way to optimize a calculation to get it to finish in the limited available memory that  you have.

Please check all this very carefully to make certain that no mistakes have been made.

Comment: Thanks Bill! Your explanation was very clear, although images aren't loading - for me, at least. I understand what you are saying. I'll have to think a bit more on the problem, then, and see how I can reduce it.